# Cordova Firebase Facebook Login Not Working

Tags: facebook, cordova, firebase

There's a tutorial for how to sign in with Firebase using Cordova, but no tutorial for Facebook with Firebase. Because signInWithPopup isn't available, what do I do?

NOTE: I'm not using Ionic.

Comment: Read this, perhaps: 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login

Comment: That's for web, not for Cordova. Cordova this doesn't work.